# Makefile rule which can can choose to update output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a metadata dotfile which I store alongside my code (in each dir of a large project).  This metadata file has a list of files in each directory that satisfies a particular constraint (not being auto-generated).  This metadata is `sinclude`d in Makefile.

I want to dep other targets (the auto-generated files) on this metadata file.  If ever the list of "real" code files in a dir changes, update this metadata file, which will in turn cause the auto-generated files (plural) to be re-made.

I have a rule for the metadata file, and when that rule fires `make` restarts correctly.  But I can't quite figure how to describe what I want.  I want the rule to run but only consider $@ as having been changed iff I actually touch the file.  I can't use the timestamp of the dir because the  act of auto-generating file A causes the timestamp to change, which triggers the need to re-generate file B, which cause the timestamp to change ...

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I can not put my finger on it...

```
all: prep my-bin

# For demonstration purposes.
prep: real-code.foobar
real-code.foobar:
        @touch real-code.foobar

my-bin: meta real-code.foobar genfile-A.foobar genfile-B.foobar genfile-C.foobar
        touch $@
meta: .
        F=$$(ls *.foobar | grep -v genfile); \
        echo "FILES := $$F" > $@

sinclude meta


genfile-A.foobar: meta
        touch $@

genfile-B.foobar: meta
        touch $@

genfile-C.foobar: meta
        touch $@

clean:
        rm -f *.foobar my-bin meta
```

Comment: Just in case this is an XY problem, please either provide some info on the content of the files you're generating, or a minimal example with real code. Depending on what `.foobar` is there may be better ways of going about this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `touch .` or `touch $@` in your meta target?

Comment: The .foobar are actually .go files.  The generated files are per-directory code that must live in the same directory (so says Go).

Answer (score 0):

You could update the meta in a shell script at the beginning of the Makefile:

```
$(shell ls *.foobar | grep -v genfile > meta.tmp; \
  diff -q meta.tmp meta && mv meta.tmp meta || rm meta.tmp)
```

This way the timestamp of meta is only updated if it changes, and it is updated before make has decided which rules to run (meaning dependencies of meta will not automatically rerun).

John

Comment: This is sort of painful because there are a lot of dirs which get this treatment (several hundred), and some recursive make invocations, and it ends up taking 5-10 seconds just to run this on each make. :(

Comment: As you pointed out, timestamp can't be used directly, as the date of the folder changes with the autogenerated files.  So, the only real way to look for what you want is to use `ls`, `grep`, and some sort of diff each time.   The above solution adds an `mv` and `rm`, which can be replaced with a virtual file, but other than that, you're not going to get much faster...